# Wrong xml schema from datatable

Tags: c#, xml, datatable

I try to write an xml file from a datatable.

```
for (int i = 0; i < ValToAppendDt.Count; i++)
        {
            DataRow row = ResultDT.NewRow();
            row[i] = ValToAppendDt[i].ToString();
            ResultDT.Rows.Add(row);
        }
        ResultDT.WriteXml(@"\\blabla\" + Environment.MachineName + ".xml");
```

This results in this xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<DocumentElement>
  <ResultsTable>
    <PC_Name>blabla</PC_Name>
  </ResultsTable>
  <ResultsTable>
    <PC_Network_Card>blabla</PC_Network_Card>
  </ResultsTable>
  <ResultsTable>
    <PC_Mac>blabla</PC_Mac>
  </ResultsTable>
</DocumentElement>
```

So when I try to import this into excel, the first value appears in A1, the second in B2, third in C3...

I'd like to have them in A1, B1, C1... But I can't fiind a way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was mystaking in my for Loop...
I changed it to :

```
DataRow row = ResultDT.NewRow();
for (int i = 0; i < ValToAppendDt.Count; i++)
    {            
        row[i] = ValToAppendDt[i].ToString();            
    }
ResultDT.Rows.Add(row);
```

working fine now...